# how to import opencv lib into other lib using g++

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, java-native-interface, g++

How can I set properly the makefile to import some OpenCV lib into the libmat.o?

this is the make file:

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Debug: -g3=compile with extra debugg infos. -ggdbg3=include things like macro defenitions. -O0=turn off optimizations.
DEBUGFLAGS = -g3 -ggdb3 -O0
CFLAGS = $(DEBUGFLAGS)

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : libMat.so

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
libMat.so : libMat.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -W -shared -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
libMat.o : Mat2Image.cpp Mat2Image.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include/linux -c $< -o $@ -L/usr/local/lib

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
# manually this would be: javah -classpath ../bin HelloJNI
HelloJNI.h : Mat2Image.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm -f Mat2Image.h libMat.o libMat.so
```

i need some OpenCV lib located in /usr/local/lib
for example libopencv_imgproc.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is get (e.g.) `libopencv_imgproc.so`,
located in `/usr/local/lib`, to be linked with your shared library `libMat.so`.

The way you are trying to do this in your makefile is by "linking"
`libopencv_imgproc.so` with the object file `libMat.o` by the recipe:

```
libMat.o : Mat2Image.cpp Mat2Image.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include \
        -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include/linux -c $< -o $@ \
        -L/usr/local/lib
```

You think that `-L/usr/local/lib` at the end will in some way let the linker
know you want to link `libopencv_imgproc.so` and do so.

That won't work for more than one reason:

`-L/usr/local/lib` will just tell the linker that `/usr/local/lib` is
a directory where you want it search for libraries that you ask it to
link. It doesn't ask it to *link* any libraries from there, and if you
don't tell it to, it won't. To tell the linker
to search for libraries in `/usr/local/lib` *and* ask it to link
`libopencv_imgproc.so` you would use:

```
`-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_imgproc
```

But you don't need to tell it to search for libraries in `/usr/local/lib`,
because that is one of the directories the linker searches for libraries
by default. So `-lopencv_imgproc` is all you would need.

But more important than that,

```
g++ $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include \
            -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include/linux -c $< -o $@ \
            -L/usr/local/lib
```

is the command that simply *compiles* `libMat.o` from `Mat2Image.cpp`. It
doesn't do any linkage. It is not possible and does not make sense to "link"
anything with an object file. So adding any linkage options to your
compile command is pointless. The compiler will ignore them. This command is
effectively no different from:

```
g++ $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include \
            -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/include/linux -c $< -o $@
```

and that's what it should be.

The recipe that does your linkage is:

```
libMat.so : libMat.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -W -shared -o $@ $<
```

So this is where you have to tell the linker that you want `libopencv_imgproc.so`
to be linked:

```
libMat.so : libMat.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -W -shared -o $@ $< -lopencv_imgproc
```

With this, `libMat.so` will be linked containing `libMat.o` and a runtime
dependency on the shared library `libopencv_imgproc.so` - that is, an
instruction to the runtime loader that it must load `libopencv_imgproc.so`
into the same process when it loads `libMat.so`.

Your makefile has various other faults but what I've said is enough to
explain and fix the particular problem I think you're asking about. You
can learn how to write a better makefile, if you want, by searching for tutorials
and ariticles about `GNU Make` and studying [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

I'll just point out one other fault that is serious. Your recipe:

```
clean:
    rm -f Mat2Image.h libMat.o libMat.so
```

is going to delete the header file `Mat2Image.h` when you run
`make clean`. That header file is one of your original source files. It
isn't generated by this makefile - like `libMat.o` and `libMat.so` - unless
you've ommitted some bits of the real makefile. So
if you delete it you'll have to recover it from you source-control system; and
if its not under a source-control system, you'll have to rewrite it. So
I think you just want:

```
clean:
    rm -f libMat.o libMat.so
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved my like! :)

Comment: @MicheleBuzzoni You're welcome :) Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @MicheleBuzzoni No problem. Just showing you how SO works.